# How to create a dynamic gridview?

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I want my grid view to look something like this.

This is my agenda Table:
[image]

How can I create a grid view / table which can be viewed as in the pic above.
I have worked with simple grid views in the past, binding them to a data source, but this is more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowSpan and ColSpan in GridView programmatically. You will have to use the `OnRowDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //chech if the row is the header
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            //span 3 columns, starting with the first one (0)
            e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 3;

            //remove the other 2 column cells
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(2);
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
        }
        //check if the row is a datarow
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //the last rownumber of the rows to be spanned, can only count backwards because next row does not exist yet.
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 8)
            {
                //amount of rows to be spanned
                int rowSpanCount = 4;

                //find the first cell counting backwards (8 - rowSpanCount)
                GridViewRow firstRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - rowSpanCount];
                firstRow.Cells[1].RowSpan = rowSpanCount;

                //hide the other cells that are part of the rowspan
                for (int i = 1; i < rowSpanCount; i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow nextRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - i];
                    nextRow.Cells[1].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my snippet the HeaderRow will span all 3 columns and cell 4, column 1 will span 4 rows.